# Rust UTF-8 error, thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()

Tags: utf-8, rust

I'm working on [cryptopals challenge set 1 challenge 3](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/3):

> The hex encoded string:
>
> ```
> 1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736
> ```
>
> ... has been XOR'd against a single character. Find the key, decrypt the message.
>
> You can do this by hand. But don't: write code to do it for you.
>
> How? Devise some method for "scoring" a piece of English plaintext. Character frequency is a good metric. Evaluate each output and choose the one with the best score.

I've programmed this:

```
extern crate num_traits;

use num_traits::pow;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut hex_string = String::new();
    let mut bin_string = String::new();
    let mut vec_bin: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut vec_plain: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    println!("Please enter the string: ");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut hex_string)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    bin_string = string_to_hex(hex_string.trim());
    for i in 0..256 {
        let mut tmp = bin_string.clone();
        vec_bin.push(xor(tmp, i));
    }
    for s in vec_bin {
        let mut vec_utf8: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        for i in 0..(s.len() / 8) {
            vec_utf8.push(bits_to_int(s[(i * 8)..((i * 8) + 8)].to_string()));
        }
        vec_plain.push(String::from_utf8(vec_utf8).unwrap());
    }
    for s in vec_plain {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}

fn string_to_hex(text: &str) -> String {
    let mut hex_string = String::new();
    for c in text.chars() {
        hex_string.push_str(&hex_to_bits(c));
    }
    hex_string
}

fn hex_to_bits(c: char) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let x = c.to_digit(16).unwrap();
    let mut tmp = x;
    while tmp != 0 {
        result = (tmp % 2).to_string() + &result;
        tmp = tmp / 2;
    }
    while result.len() < 4 {
        result = "0".to_string() + &result;
    }
    result
}

fn xor(s: String, u: u16) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let bin = dec_to_bin(u);
    for i in 0..(s.len() / 8) {
        let mut tmp = bin.clone();
        result = result + &single_byte_xor(s[(i * 8)..((i * 8) + 8)].to_string(), tmp);
    }
    result
}

fn dec_to_bin(u: u16) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let mut tmp = u;
    while tmp != 0 {
        result = (tmp % 2).to_string() + &result;
        tmp = tmp / 2;
    }
    while result.len() < 8 {
        result = "0".to_string() + &result;
    }
    result
}

fn single_byte_xor(s: String, u: String) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    for i in 0..s.len() {
        if &s[i..(i + 1)] == "1" && &u[i..(i + 1)] == "1" {
            result = result + &"0".to_string();
        } else if &s[i..(i + 1)] == "1" || &u[i..(i + 1)] == "1" {
            result = result + &"1".to_string();
        } else {
            result = result + &"0".to_string();
        }
    }
    result
}

fn bits_to_int(s: String) -> u8 {
    let mut result: u8 = 0;
    let mut counter = 0;
    for c in s.chars().rev() {
        let x = c.to_digit(10).unwrap();
        if x == 1 {
            result += pow(2u8, counter);
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
    result
}
```

When I run the program, I get this error:

```
Please enter the string: 

1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: FromUtf8Error { bytes: [155, 183, 183, 179, 177, 182, 191, 248, 149, 155, 255, 171, 248, 180, 177, 179, 189, 248, 185, 248, 168, 183, 173, 182, 188, 248, 183, 190, 248, 186, 185, 187, 183, 182], error: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 0, error_len: Some(1) } }', /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:916:5
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::unix::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace
         at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:49
   1: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
         at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:68
         at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:57
   2: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:381
   3: std::panicking::default_hook
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:397
   4: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:577
   5: std::panicking::begin_panic
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:538
   6: std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:522
   7: rust_begin_unwind
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:498
   8: core::panicking::panic_fmt
         at /checkout/src/libcore/panicking.rs:71
   9: core::result::unwrap_failed
         at /checkout/src/libcore/macros.rs:23
  10: <core::result::Result<T, E>>::unwrap
         at /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:782
  11: nr3::main
         at src/main.rs:24
  12: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
         at /checkout/src/libstd/rt.rs:74
  13: std::panicking::try::do_call
         at /checkout/src/libstd/rt.rs:59
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:480
  14: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
         at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:101
  15: std::rt::lang_start_internal
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panicking.rs:459
         at /checkout/src/libstd/panic.rs:365
         at /checkout/src/libstd/rt.rs:58
  16: std::rt::lang_start
         at /checkout/src/libstd/rt.rs:74
  17: main
  18: __libc_start_main
  19: _start
```

I can not figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Well, that byte string isn't UTF-8.

Comment: One thing to try first when getting an error is to search the web for information. Your error is a `FromUtf8Error`, so I suggest you google that and click the first hit. In general, you may want to add more context to the search terms, e.g. "Rust", but in this case [just "FromUtf8Error" does the trick](https://www.google.com/search?q=FromUtf8Error). The documentation of the error should be self-explanatory. As a solution, I suggest you work with byte vectors instead of strings, or simply discard everything with character values above 127.

Comment: Looking at the data, the easiest solution seems to be to change `for i in 0..256` to `for i in 0..128`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking if the string you've got is a valid UTF-8 string. `String::from_utf8` will check this for you and returns either `Ok(s)` or `Err(_)`. 
You should then match on the return value and either print the decoded string, or report a failure. Something like this does the trick.

```
use std::io;    

fn main() {
    let mut hex_string = "1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736";
    let raw:Vec<u8> = hex_string_to_raw(hex_string);
    for i in 0..255 {
        // Get XOR'd version
        let mut vec_utf8:Vec<u8> = raw.iter().map(|v| v ^ i ).collect();
        // Try to decode it
        let s = String::from_utf8(vec_utf8);
        match s {
            Err(_) => { println!("Failed to decode using {}", i); }
            Ok(s) => { println!("Decoded with {} to '{}'", i, s); }
        }
    }
}

fn hex_string_to_raw(hex: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let chars:Vec<char> = hex.chars().collect();
    let mut raw:Vec<u8> = vec![];
    for cs in chars.chunks(2) {
        let c0:char = cs[0];
        let c1:char = cs[1];
        raw.push( (c0.to_digit(16).unwrap()*16 + c1.to_digit(16).unwrap()) as u8);
    }
    raw
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing this

```
for s in vec_bin {
    let mut vec_utf8: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..(s.len()/8) {
        vec_utf8.push(bits_to_int(s[(i*8)..((i*8)+8)].to_string()));
    }
    vec_plain.push(String::from_utf8(vec_utf8).unwrap());
}
```

to this

```
for s in vec_bin {
    let mut vec_utf8: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..(s.len()/8) {
        vec_utf8.push(bits_to_int(s[(i*8)..((i*8)+8)].to_string()));
    }
    let mut tmp = String::new();
    tmp.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&vec_utf8));
    vec_plain.push(tmp);

}
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to interpret the essentially random strings as UTF-8 data, since they just are not. The input data is all 7-bit ASCII, and it is a reasonable assumption that the output data is also 7-bit ASCII, so if you restrict the range of keys to seven bits, the result is guaranteed to be valid 7-bit ASCII (which implies valid UTF-8).